# Cast specific types in variadic argument

Tags: c++, casting, variadic-templates, variadic-functions

I have a template function that accepts variadic arguments.

```
template<typename... Params>
void foo(Params... p);
```

I want to find all occurences of a given type (`const char*`) in `Params` to replace them with another type, that these values can be cast to (my own `Path` class with constructor `Path(const char*)`). The idea is to have something like

```
template<typename... Params>
void foo(Params... p) {
    bar<convertCharPointerToPath<Params>...>(p...);
}
```

How can this conversion be done?

Comment: what is your question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to convert types only, it's just a meta-function away:

```
template<typename T> struct convert {
  using type = T;
};

template<> struct convert<char const*> {
  using type = Path;
};

template<typename T>
using convertCharPointerToPath = typename convert<T>::type;
```

Now use it in your parameter pack expansion, as you do in your original post.

Comment: You could also use `std::conditional_t`, not sure if that is more readable than what you have though.

Comment: @Rakete1111 - I find spelling certain meta-functions out as easier to follow, myself. A conditional would give the same effect, for sure. But I think this is easier to extend to other types.

Comment: extending to `std::string` in my case ;)

Answer (score 2):

Without a traits helper:

```
template<typename... Params>
void foo(Params... p) {
  bar<std::conditional_t<std::is_same<char const*,Params>{},Path,Params>...>(p...);
}
```

or, with `overload<Fs...>`:

```
auto identity=[](auto&&x)->decltype(x){return decltype(x)(x);};

template<typename... Params>
void foo(Params... p) {
  auto convert = overload([](const char* p){return Path(p);},identity);
  bar(convert(p)...);
}
```

`overload` can be found everywhere; it takes a set of lambdas and returns their overload set.

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c54e25c6f48dc7e5).

Comment: I'm trying to use the `overload` version for a similar problem, but I cannot get it to work. The compiler complains that it cannot find a viable constructor for the `overload` object. Might the issue be that the different overloads have different return types?

Comment: @NikolausDemmel Or the version of `overload` you want needs `{}`?  Or a deduction guide?  Or your compiler doesn't support deduction guides?  Lots of stuff could go wrong.

Comment: @NikolausDemmel Compiling live example link added.

Comment: thanks for the live example. It turns out something was broken with my equivalent of `bar`. It's working for me now. For overload you have `overload(Fs&&...)->overload<std::decay_t<Fs>...>;` whereas I have `overload(Fs...)->overload<Fs...>;` (from some other place). In my case both work. I don't really understand when it would make a difference.

Comment: @NikolausDemmel That would be a good thing to use the "ask question" button to ask.  :)

Comment: Sorry for going off-topic. You are right, I'll research more and ask a question if still relevant. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Follow-up: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55087826/questions-on-lambda-overloads-type-conversions-and-perfect-forwarding