# Questions on lambda overloads, type conversions and perfect forwarding

Tags: c++, lambda, variadic-templates, perfect-forwarding

This is a question on lambda overload sets and perfect forwarding and somewhat of a followup to a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48131712/cast-specific-types-in-variadic-argument/48132612?noredirect=1#comment96860638_48132612). For more context of how this is used see [another related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55045367/generic-factory-mechanism-in-c17).

I have some questions on the below code snippet.

Q1: For lambda overloads, I was using `overload(Fs...) -> overload<Fs...>` from [this post](https://dev.to/tmr232/that-overloaded-trick-overloading-lambdas-in-c17), but then in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48132612/1813258) I saw `overload(Fs&&...) -> overload<std::decay_t<Fs>...>`. In what situations is this difference relevant?

Q2: Why would you want to define the `identity` function below with `return decltype(x)(x)` and not just `return x`?

Q3: Can we consider `foo(convert(std::forward<Args>(args))...)` as perfect forwarding (for all not-converted arguments) just like `foo(std::forward<Args>(args)...)`?

```cpp
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>


/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


struct Foo {
    virtual ~Foo() = default;
};

struct FooA: public Foo {
    static void foo(const FooA&, int) { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl; }
};

struct FooB: public Foo {
    static void foo(int, const FooB&) { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl; }
};


/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


template<class...Fs>
struct overload:Fs... {
    using Fs::operator()...;
};

// Q1: In what situations is needed over `overload(Fs...) -> overload<Fs...>`?
template<class...Fs>
overload(Fs&&...) -> overload<std::decay_t<Fs>...>;


/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


// Q2: What is the purpose of `return decltype(x)(x)` over `return x`?
auto identity=[](auto&&x)->decltype(x){return decltype(x)(x);};

template<typename SpecificFoo, typename... Args>
void bar(Args&&... args) {
  auto convert = overload{
    [](const Foo& f){return dynamic_cast<const SpecificFoo&>(f);},
    identity
  };

  // Q3: Is our definition of `convert` "perfectly forwarding", like if we just called 
  // `foo(std::forward<Args>(args)...)`, or in what situations might this not do the 
  // same thing (for not-converted types)?
  SpecificFoo::foo(convert(std::forward<Args>(args))...);
}


/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


int main() {
    {
        FooA specific_foo;
        const Foo& foo {specific_foo};
        // assume we only have access to foo when calling bar
        bar<FooA>(foo, 23);
    }
    {
        FooB specific_foo;
        const Foo& foo {specific_foo};
        // assume we only have access to foo when calling bar
        bar<FooB>(42, foo);
    }
}
```

[run it](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/149381fc7c15bf3c)

Comment: These are all good questions individually, but I'm not knowledgeable enough to say whether there's an elegant unified answer that can be applied to all three questions in one go.

Comment: @StoryTeller I have considered this, but I'd argue that the questions are closely related. It is just that I have specified the bits I don't understand, rather than just saying "how does the whole thing work"? To understand the behaviour of `convert(...)` w.r.t argument forwarding we need to understand how `identity` behaves, and while indeed `overload` is a slightly different case, the it is also about how it handles it's arguments. (So yeah, possibly Q1 should be separate, but not Q2 and Q3 for sure IMHO...).

Comment: Hm... looks like @StoryTeller deleted his original comment remarking that the question might be too broad. In any case, its answered now (thanks!), and I'll consider scope more carefully next time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> In what situations is this difference relevant?

When at least one argument is in fact an lvalue (like `identity`, in fact). In which case the corresponding `Fi` is a  `T&`, i.e. an lvalue reference. And one can't list an lvalue reference as a base of any class, so `std::decay` is required to remove all reference and cv-qualifiers. When the deduction guide takes arguments by value, it's automatically a non-issue. This is because template argument deduction for value types already "decays" the types.

If you wonder which one to use, then I'd say the one with less clutter is objectively better. The use of `std::decay_t` is for getting the same behavior one would get with the by-value version, so one may as well use that.

> Why would you want to define the identity function below with return decltype(x)(x) and not just return x

This is a form of forwarding. Since the return type of the lambda is declared to be `decltype(x)`, we need the cast to make sure it binds correctly to an rvalue reference. Because in the case `decltype(x) = T&&`, it will not bind to `x` alone, which is an lvalue.

> Can we consider `foo(convert(std::forward<Args>(args))...)` as perfect forwarding (for all not-converted arguments) just like `foo(std::forward<Args>(args)...)`

Yes. The arguments to `bar` already bound to references. `convert` lets those references pass through with value category preserved, so it's forwarding indeed.

Comment: Is it equivalent to the more idiomatic `[](auto&&x)->decltype(auto){return std::forward<decltype(x)>(x);};` ?

Comment: @Oktalist - Yup. Was just adding it in.

Comment: You didn't add in the `std::forward` though?

Comment: @Oktalist - Actually, scratch that. Clang rejects it, and I'm not longer sure.

Comment: @Oktalist - The `std::forward` serves the exact same purpose of the cast. The thing I'm not certain about is whether or not `decltype(auto)` means `return x` is enough.

Comment: No, `return x;` isn't enough, as `x` is an lvalue.

Comment: @Oktalist - Tell that to GCC. I'm looking for a CWG issue since skimming through the standard didn't reassure me.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! So if I understand correctly w.r.t. Q1, `overload(Fs...) -> overload<Fs...>` also works in this case because then the constructor makes copies, but `overload(Fs&&...) -> overload<Fs...>` wouldn't work because it would try to derive from a reference and/or cv qualified type. About convert and identity, I think I now understand this with in the different cases rvalues and lvalues and references. Just about `-> decltype(auto)` for the comments I'll have to read up.

Comment: @NikolausDemmel - Yes, you could favor by-value arguments, I suppose. It won't affect the initialization itself since the deduction guide doesn't relate to it. Overload resolution happens twice. Once for a deduction guide, and another time if initialization requires it.

Comment: @StoryTeller Yeah now I think you're right, `return x;` should be enough. The return operand is an unparenthesized id-expression, so the deduced type is `decltype(x)`. This is one of those cases where `return x` and `return (x)` behave differently. I think I prefer it with `std::forward` just to be explicit.

Comment: Such favouring of by-value arguments is the advice I've seen given for some of the more complex deduction guides. The fact that by-value performance isn't relevant for deduction guides means that eliminating the possibility of every type maybe being a reference can simplify things greatly and generally Just Work™.

Comment: @Oktalist - I thought it would be enough. But here's the issue, `decltype(x)` is an rvalue reference, so Clang refuses to bind `x` (an lvalue) to it. I think we're supposed to stick with forwarding explicitly here.

Comment: @StoryTeller, thanks for the edit. I think a statement like "both by-value and using decay_t type do the same thing, and there is no reason not the prefer the simpler by-value version" would be helpful for other readers. I guess my Q1 should have been: "which variant should I be using".

Comment: PS: Or rather, the true answer to "In what situations is this difference relevant?" should maybe be "never (for this deduction guide)", or not?

Comment: @NikolausDemmel - Fine, added another note. But honestly, I think you are overthinking the answer at this point. I think people can now reach a conclusion easily without making the answer any more verbose.